# Sales-Commission 8.10 Dietel

Tags: c#

> I can't figure out why I keep getting the "Index was outside the
>   bounds of the array" error. I am trying to tally up the salaries to
>   display.
>   Is there are any someone who could explain to me how the error message works.

```
namespace sales_commission {
    class Program {
        static void Main (string[] args) {
            const int ARRAY_LENGTH = 8;


            int[] salaries = { 210, 400, 450, 950, 800, 330, 430, 233, 223, 590, 679, 1000 };

            var salary = new int[ARRAY_LENGTH];

            foreach(int number in salaries) {

                try {
                    if (number >= 200 && number <= 299) {
                        salary[0]++;
                    } else if (number >= 300 && number <= 399) {
                        salary[1]++;
                    } else if (number >= 400 && number <= 499) {
                        salary[2]++;
                    } else if (number >= 500 && number <= 599) {
                        salary[3]++;
                    } else if (number >= 600 && number <= 699) {
                        salary[4]++;
                    } else if (number >= 700 && number <= 799) {
                        salary[5]++;
                    } else if (number >= 800 && number <= 899) {
                        salary[6]++;
                    } else if (number >= 900 && number <= 999) {
                        salary[7]++;
                    } else if (number >= 1000) {
                        salary[8]++;
                    }
                } catch (IndexOutOfRangeException ex) {
                    Console.WriteLine (ex.Message);
                    Console.WriteLine ($"salaries[{number}] = {salary[number]}");
                }

            }

            for (var result = 0; result <= salary.Length; ++result) {
                Console.WriteLine ($"{result* 100 + 200} - {result * 100 + 200 + 99}  {salary[result],15}");
            }



        }
    }
}
```

Comment: IMHO, look at using `List<int>` it would make this cleaner, maintainable and easier to do what you want. Also what line throws the error? `Index was outside the bounds of the array` as for this, in short, you're trying to access an index that's not there (so outside the bounds).

Comment: Anyways, change `const int ARRAY_LENGTH = 8;` to `const int ARRAY_LENGTH = 9;` and then change `for (var result = 0; result <= salary.Length; ++result)` that line to `for (var result = 0; result <= salary.Length - 1; ++result)` arrays start at `0`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 9 salary brackets.  200-299, 300-399, 400-499, 500-599, 600-699, 700-799, 800-899, 900-999 and >= 1000.  That means you need 9 storage spaces for the counts.  Array indexes start at 0, so your array length needs to be 9, this gives you [0 to 8] indexes.

```
const int ARRAY_LENGTH = 8;    // This needs to be 9.
```

You get an array out of bounds because:

```
} else if (number >= 1000) {
    salary[8]++;              // Index 8 doesn't exist, only [0 to 7] for an ARRAY_LENGTH of 8.
```

Your loop also accesses data outside of the array bounds.  This is because the condition of your loop runs until it reaches **and includes** the index of the length itself.  So if your array has 8 spaces [0 to 7], your loop runs from [0 to 8] and the moment it access index 8, you're out of bounds.  This can easily be fixed as below:-

```
for (var result = 0; result <= salary.Length; ++result) {  // Change this to result < salary.Length
    Console.WriteLine ($"{result* 100 + 200} - {result * 100 + 200 + 99 {salary[result],15}");
}
```